# How to configure rancher cluster(deployment) to accept SignalR connections?

Tags: docker, signalr, rancher

I've a problem connecting to SignalR hub on server deployed on rancher. Everything works fine locally but when I deploy it to rancher I get below error

```
Error: Failed to start the connection: Error: WebSocket failed to connect. 
The connection could not be found on the server, either the endpoint may not be a SignalR endpoint,
 the connection ID is not present on the server, or there is a proxy blocking WebSockets. 
If you have multiple servers check that sticky sessions are enabled.
```

**This is my deployment configuration**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: websocket
  annotations:
    deployment.kubernetes.io/revision: '38'
    field.cattle.io/publicEndpoints: 'null'
#    key: string
  creationTimestamp: '2023-09-06T15:02:45Z'
  generation: 55
  labels:
    workload.user.cattle.io/workloadselector: apps.deployment-verification-ns-websocket
#    key: string
  namespace: verification-ns
  resourceVersion: '30316034'
  uid: fb013268-7edc-4b24-8601-743cc5b88999
  fields:
    - websocket
    - 1/1
    - 1
    - 1
    - 13d
    - container-0
    - harbor.company.tech/verification/dev/websocket:latest
    - >-
      workload.user.cattle.io/workloadselector=apps.deployment-verification-ns-websocket
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      workload.user.cattle.io/workloadselector: apps.deployment-verification-ns-websocket
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        workload.user.cattle.io/workloadselector: apps.deployment-verification-ns-websocket
      annotations:
        cattle.io/timestamp: '2023-09-19T14:26:26Z'
        field.cattle.io/ports: >-
          [[{"containerPort":80,"dnsName":"websocket","kind":"ClusterIP","name":"p80","protocol":"TCP"},{"containerPort":443,"dnsName":"websocket","kind":"ClusterIP","name":"p443","protocol":"TCP"}]]
      creationTimestamp: 
    spec:
      containers:
        - env:
            - name: SQLSERVER
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  key: connectionString
                  name: connections
                  optional: false
          image: harbor.company.tech/verification/dev/websocket:latest
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          name: container-0
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
              name: p80
              protocol: TCP
              _serviceType: ClusterIP
          terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
          terminationMessagePolicy: File
          __active: true
          resources: {}
      affinity:
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: harbor
      restartPolicy: Always
      schedulerName: default-scheduler
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
      volumes:
  progressDeadlineSeconds: 600
  replicas: 1
  revisionHistoryLimit: 10
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 25%
      maxUnavailable: 25%
    type: RollingUpdate
__clone: true
```

**This is my service configuration**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    field.cattle.io/publicEndpoints: "null"
    field.cattle.io/targetWorkloadIds: '["verification-ns/websocket"]'
    management.cattle.io/ui-managed: "true"
  creationTimestamp: "2023-09-06T15:16:32Z"
  managedFields:
  - apiVersion: v1
    fieldsType: FieldsV1
    fieldsV1:
      f:metadata:
        f:annotations:
          .: {}
          f:field.cattle.io/publicEndpoints: {}
          f:field.cattle.io/targetWorkloadIds: {}
          f:management.cattle.io/ui-managed: {}
      f:spec:
        f:allocateLoadBalancerNodePorts: {}
        f:externalTrafficPolicy: {}
        f:internalTrafficPolicy: {}
        f:ports:
          .: {}
          k:{"port":80,"protocol":"TCP"}:
            .: {}
            f:name: {}
            f:port: {}
            f:protocol: {}
            f:targetPort: {}
        f:selector: {}
        f:sessionAffinity: {}
        f:type: {}
    manager: agent
    operation: Update
    time: "2023-09-20T05:43:07Z"
  - apiVersion: v1
    fieldsType: FieldsV1
    fieldsV1:
      f:status:
        f:loadBalancer:
          f:ingress: {}
    manager: controller
    operation: Update
    subresource: status
    time: "2023-09-20T05:43:07Z"
  name: websocket
  namespace: verification-ns
  resourceVersion: "30316031"
  uid: 81e8fb2e-be75-48b1-a4dd-f5e7d6f82428
spec:
  clusterIP: 12.13.146.55
  clusterIPs:
  - 12.13.146.55
  internalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
  ipFamilies:
  - IPv4
  ipFamilyPolicy: SingleStack
  ports:
  - name: p80
    port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 80
  selector:
    workload.user.cattle.io/workloadselector: apps.deployment-verification-ns-websocket
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: ClusterIP
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

**And this is my ngnix.conf**

```
worker_processes  5;  ## Default: 1
worker_rlimit_nofile 8192;
 
events {
    worker_connections  4096;  ## Default: 1024
}
 
 
http {
    default_type application/octet-stream;
    sendfile     on;
    tcp_nopush   on;
    server_names_hash_bucket_size 128; # this seems to be required for some vhosts
 
    client_max_body_size 500M;
 
    server {
        listen       80;        
 
 
        location /areyouok {
            add_header  Content-Type    text;
            return 200 'yes';
        } 
        
        location /verification/websocket/api/  {
            # redirect all HTTP traffic to localhost:8080
            proxy_pass http://websocket.verification-ns.svc.cluster.local/verification/websocket/api/;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

            # WebSocket support
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        }

        location /verification/websocket/swagger/ {
            proxy_pass http://websocket.verification-ns.svc.cluster.local/verification/websocket/swagger/;
        }       
    }
}
```

I've tried and changed some settings up and down in rancher as I'm mostly sure it has to do with something in there for example load balancer or sticky sessions. I've tried to search and try everything on forums but still can't find a solution. Would be great to have at least direction where to look If anyone had same experience with signalR and rancher.

Rancher version v2.6.8

Comment: Show kubectl get events,to get more information,

Comment: I've done this and it returned this:

> kubectl get events -n verification-ns

No resources found in verification-ns namespace.